# Cannot acces camera and microphone working in a WebView

Tags: java, android, audio, webview, camera

I'm trying to access Camera and Microphone for my WebView. I've added the uses permissions on Manifest. I also added uses feature. The permissions in runtime are also have been declared. I wonder what's wrong with this. These are my codes.

Error:

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
[ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
E/CameraManagerGlobal: [yinyapeng_cts]
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.hal1.packagelist"
E/CameraManagerGlobal: [yinyapeng_cts]
E/Camera: Camera  err=0
A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 in tid 6630 (m.apps.example), pid 6630 (m.apps.example)
```

Manifest Permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.output"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_post_processing"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_sensor"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.capability.raw"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.external"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.level.full"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
```

WebView.setWebChromeClient

```
@Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                myRequest = request;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
                        switch (permission) {
                            case "android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE": {
                                askForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, 101);
                                myRequest.grant(request.getResources());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

onRequestPermissionResult

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                myRequest.grant(myRequest.getResources());
                webView.loadUrl("https://webcamera.io/id/");
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Declined", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

askForPermission method

```
public void askForPermission(String origin, String permission, int requestCode) {
    Log.d("WebView", "inside askForPermission for" + origin + "with" + permission);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                permission)) {

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{permission},
                    requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            myRequest.grant(myRequest.getResources());
        }
    }
}
```

If there's anyone who knows the solution. Kindly reply. Thanks!

Comment: have you found any solution?